# Function Not Defined OEmbed Vimeo API

Tags: javascript, jquery

Started messing around with Vimeo API in an attempt to create a clickable gallery like this (http://www.aideffectiveness.org/busanhlf4/vimeo/php-example.php). However, when I moved some of the code into a "script.js" file as a way to organize my code from the other parts of the site, the json callback keeps saying that the 'embedVideo' function is not defined. Any ideas?

The "script.js" file is placed at the bottom of the page and has the following:

```
var NS = NS || NS;

NS = {

  videoInit: function() {

    var oEmbedUrl = 'http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json';
    var oEmbedCallback = 'embedVideo';
    var videoid =  "";

    if(videoid == '' ){
        videoid = '23515961';
    }

    function embedVideo( video ) {
        var videoEmbedCode = video.html;
        document.getElementById('embed').innerHTML = unescape(videoEmbedCode);
    }

    function init() {
      loadScript(oEmbedUrl + '?url=http://vimeo.com/' + videoid + '&height=380&width=700&callback=' + oEmbedCallback);
    }

    function loadScript( url ) {
        var js = document.createElement('script');
        js.setAttribute('src', url);
       document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(js);
    }

    init();
  }
}
$(function() {
   NS.videoInit();
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="embed"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`embedVideo` is a local (private) function inside of the init method. Nothing outside it can see it.  That's why your AJAX callback is throwing that error.

You can fix this by making `embedVideo` a proper *method* of NS, so that's it's visible to your ajax callback

```
NS = {
  embedVideo: function( video ) {
    var videoEmbedCode = video.html;
    document.getElementById('embed').innerHTML = unescape(videoEmbedCode);
  },

  videoInit: function() {

    var oEmbedUrl = 'http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json';
    var oEmbedCallback = 'embedVideo';
    var videoid =  "";

    if(videoid == '' ){
        videoid = '23515961';
    }
```

Comment: I placed this code within my script file however it still tells me that the embedVideo is undefined. However this worked: is there a way to make it cleaner. 

    `function embedVideo( video ) {

        var videoEmbedCode = video.html;

        document.getElementById('embed').innerHTML = unescape(videoEmbedCode);

    }

    NS = {...}
`

Comment: I would just make embedVideo a method of NS.  Or you could attach it to some other utility object.  Either way, it'll never work as a local function inside of Init.

Comment: This is what I have right now. When the embedVideo is a method of NS, it still doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/Kwmtn/3/

Comment: There's no JS in this fiddle.  Also, once you add embedVideo to NS, you have to **call it** from NS -> `NS.embedVideo()`

Comment: Wow how did I miss that. This worked: `var oEmbedCallback = 'NS.embedVideo';` Thanks for all your help!